# Как исправить ошибку php (idn_to_utf8(): INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 is deprecated)

Tags: php

Не запускается проект, падает ошибка в данном коде, backend не оч поэтому задаю вопрос, как исправить?

```html
class CurrentSiteMiddleware extends Middleware
{
    public function processRequest(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Console::isCli()) {
            $modelClass = Mindy::app()->getModule('Sites')->modelClass;
            $model = $modelClass::objects()->filter([
                'domain' => $this->decode($request->http->getHost()),
            ])->get();
            if ($model !== null) {
                Mindy::app()->getModule('Sites')->setSite($model);
            }
        }
    }

    public function decode($value)
    {
        if (function_exists('idn_to_utf8')) {
            return idn_to_utf8($value);
        } elseif (class_exists('\True\Punycode')) {
            $pc = new \True\Punycode(Mindy::app()->locale['charset']);

            return $pc->decode($value);
        }
        Mindy::app()->logger->error('CurrentSiteMiddleware required php intl or \\True\\Punycode packages');

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум укажите ошибку и соответственно непонятно, что у Вас в классе Middleware

Answer (score 0):

Все просто - вы вызываете функцию idn_to_utf8($value)

в $value вы кидаете INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003

7.2.0   INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003 объявлена устаревшей, вместо нее используйте INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46.

Comment: надо еще понять где вы еще вызываете CurrentSiteMiddleware::decode()  в вашем случае нужно понять почему $request->http->getHost() отдает INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003